# Check numpy array if a row contains at least one false

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, numpy, boolean

I have an array 2*n of True and False boolean.

```
array([[False,  True],
       [False,  True],
       [False,  True],
       ...,
       [False,  True],
       [False,  True],
       [False,  True]])
```

What I want is a new vector, can be in another array that has False if any of the two values are False. 
I can create a loop and check each value in the row, and make a new vector. but I'm guessing it's slow

```
boidx = np.empty(len(minindex), dtype=bool)

for idx in range(len(minindex)):
    if minindex[idx,0] and minindex[idx,1]:
        boidx[idx]=True
    else:
        boidx[idx]=False
```

but this is long and not pythonic. 
The array is either 2n or 4n. so it should cover those options (my for loop does not)
but if needed, two solutions with an if for size is doable.
I also tried to use numpy.isin() command. but it works for each cell. I need per row.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As an answer already pointed out, you can use [numpy.all()](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.all.html) to solve it.

A simpler formulation without any loop would be:

```
np.all(minindex, axis=1)
```

Comment: @sentence I'm actually not sure if `np.logical_and(minindex[:, 0], minindex[:, 1])` would be even faster. It surely looks neater with `np.all` though

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, a pythonic solution could use [`numpy.all`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.all.html):

```
import numpy as np

minindex = np.array([[False,  True],
                     [False,  True],
                     [True,  True],
                     [True,  False],
                     [False,  True],
                     [False,  False],
                     [False,  False],
                     [True,  True]

boidx = np.array([np.all(i) for i in minindex])
```

and you get:

`[False False  True False False False False  True]`

Another solution could be the use of `prod`:

```
boidx = np.array([bool(i.prod()) for i in minindex])
```

and you get the same result.

---

As suggested by @Jianyu, this way should be definitely faster:

`boidx = np.all(minindex, axis=1)`

Comment: Similarly, `minindex.prod(1)` should be used instead of your unpack-repack list comprehension (in cases where `prod` is more applicable than `all`).